# How can i update quantity in the django cart?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**model.py**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        customer = request.user.customer
        order ,created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
        if OrderItem.objects.filter(product=product):
                orderitem = OrderItem.objects.filter(product=product)
                orderitem.quantity+=1
                order.save()

            
        else:
            orderitem = OrderItem.objects.create(product=product,order=order,quantity=1)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "HTML/index.html",{'products':products})
```

**Error**

`QuerySet' object has no attribute 'quantity'`

I'm trying to a cart if an item exists in this cart, the system should update its quantity, if not then a new item should be created in the cart, how can i do that?

Comment: You only need use a id, for search a item and use print(order) to see the product data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the @STACCAH_STACCAH answer is not fully correct, you can have multiple `OrderItem` instances attached to the product. So you should do this that way:

```py
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(product=product)
for item in order_items:
    item.quantity += 1
    item.save()
```

It's should be enough, you don't need to check if the object exist at all because `QuerySet` is iterable even when amount of elements is certainly zero. Basically that means `forloop` will not raise exception while iterating on `OrderItem` instances.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, you are trying to set the attribute of a QuerySet instead of an object. You can change all of the objects within a queryset using the `.update()` function and `F()` expression and a single line:

```py
from django.db.models import F

OrderItem.objects.filter(product=product).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
```

You don't need to check if they exist or use a for loop, much cleaner.